# Sending 2 fetched result into AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, chart.js

**EDIT**
    success:function(res)
        {
          var costData = [];
          var costData2 = [];

```
        costData.push(res['income']);
        costData2.push(res['instIncome']);



        var areaChartData = {
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"
          , "September", "October", "November", "December"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Cash Income",
              strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: costData
            }
          ]
        };
        var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);
        var barChartData = areaChartData;
        barChartData.datasets[0].fillColor = "#00a65a";
        barChartData.datasets[0].strokeColor = "#00a65a";
        barChartData.datasets[0].pointColor = "#00a65a";
        var barChartOptions = {
          //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
          scaleBeginAtZero: true,
          //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
          scaleShowGridLines: true,
          //String - Colour of the grid lines
          scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
          //Number - Width of the grid lines
          scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
          //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
          scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
          //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
          scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
          //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
          barShowStroke: true,
          //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
          barStrokeWidth: 2,
          //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
          barValueSpacing: 5,
          //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
          barDatasetSpacing: 1,
          //String - A legend template
          legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
          //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true
        };

        barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
        barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
      }
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT 
    sum(cost) as cost

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        sum(project_cost) as cost, 
        month(date_now) as month 
    FROM 
        dentist.patient_info 
    WHERE id_logged=:logged AND year(date_now)=:year_now AND payment_type=:pt 
    GROUP BY month(date_now)
    UNION
    SELECT 
        sum(payment), 
        month(date_now) 
    FROM 
       debt
    WHERE year(debt.date_now)=:year_now
    UNION SELECT 0,1
    UNION SELECT 0,2
    UNION SELECT 0,3
    UNION SELECT 0,4
    UNION SELECT 0,5
    UNION SELECT 0,6
    UNION SELECT 0,7
    UNION SELECT 0,8
    UNION SELECT 0,9
    UNION SELECT 0,10
    UNION SELECT 0,11
    UNION SELECT 0,12
) tmp
GROUP BY month";
$sqlStmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":pt", $c);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
$exec = $sqlStmt->execute();
$res1 = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

$sql2 = "SELECT 
    sum(cost) as cost

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        sum(payment) as cost, 
        month(date_now) as month 
    FROM 
        debt 
    WHERE id_logged=:logged AND year(date_now)=:year_now  
    GROUP BY month(date_now)

    UNION SELECT 0,1
    UNION SELECT 0,2
    UNION SELECT 0,3
    UNION SELECT 0,4
    UNION SELECT 0,5
    UNION SELECT 0,6
    UNION SELECT 0,7
    UNION SELECT 0,8
    UNION SELECT 0,9
    UNION SELECT 0,10
    UNION SELECT 0,11
    UNION SELECT 0,12
) tmp
GROUP BY month";
$sqlStmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$sqlStmt2->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
$sqlStmt2->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
$exec2 = $sqlStmt2->execute();
$res2 = $sqlStmt2->fetchAll();

$res['income']=$res1;
$res['instIncome']=$res2;

echo json_encode($res);
```

Result:

[image]

No data displayed

**END EDIT**

I have this PHP code that make the sum of income for each month:

```
$res = array();
    $c = "cash";
    $i = "installment";
    //SUM of cash paid Month
    $sql = "SELECT 
    sum(cost) as cost

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        sum(project_cost) as cost, 
        month(date_now) as month 
    FROM 
        dentist.patient_info 
    WHERE id_logged=:logged AND year(date_now)=:year_now AND payment_type=:pt 
    GROUP BY month(date_now)
    UNION
    SELECT 
        sum(payment), 
        month(date_now) 
    FROM 
       debt
    WHERE year(debt.date_now)=:year_now
    UNION SELECT 0,1
    UNION SELECT 0,2
    UNION SELECT 0,3
    UNION SELECT 0,4
    UNION SELECT 0,5
    UNION SELECT 0,6
    UNION SELECT 0,7
    UNION SELECT 0,8
    UNION SELECT 0,9
    UNION SELECT 0,10
    UNION SELECT 0,11
    UNION SELECT 0,12
) tmp
GROUP BY month";
$sqlStmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":logged", $id_logged);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":pt", $c);
$sqlStmt->bindValue(":year_now", $date1);
$exec = $sqlStmt->execute();
$res = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($res);
```

The result is sent back to AJAX success function and displayed into a bar chart using `ChartJS`.

Now I need to create on the same chart another bar for the outcome. 
Here is the script:

```
success:function(res)
    {
      var costData = [];
      $.each(res, function( key, row)
      {
        costData.push(row['cost']);
      });


        var areaChartData = {
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"
          , "September", "October", "November", "December"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Cash Income",
              strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: costData
            }
          ]
        };
        var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);
        var barChartData = areaChartData;
        barChartData.datasets[0].fillColor = "#00a65a";
        barChartData.datasets[0].strokeColor = "#00a65a";
        barChartData.datasets[0].pointColor = "#00a65a";
        var barChartOptions = {
          //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
          scaleBeginAtZero: true,
          //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
          scaleShowGridLines: true,
          //String - Colour of the grid lines
          scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
          //Number - Width of the grid lines
          scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
          //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
          scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
          //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
          scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
          //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
          barShowStroke: true,
          //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
          barStrokeWidth: 2,
          //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
          barValueSpacing: 5,
          //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
          barDatasetSpacing: 1,
          //String - A legend template
          legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
          //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true
        };

        barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
        barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
      }
```

My Problem is at the PHP code. How should I add another query and fetch into a variable `$res2` and combine it with `$res` and then I will split them into `i.e $res['income'] and $res['outcome']` in `success:function`.

How do I send couple of fetched arrays into one `json_encode`

Comment: Why cant you combine both array into one before encoding ? Am i missing something here ?

Comment: How do I do that ? This is my main problem

Answer (score 0):

In your php code

```
$res1 = $sqlStmt->fetchAll();
$res2 = $sqlStmt2->fetchAll(); // Assuming u have executed 2nd query.
$res['income'] = $res1; 
$res['outcome'] = $res2;
echo json_encode($res);
```

Your Ajax Success

```
success:function(res){

   $incomeData = res['income'];
   $outcomeData = res['outcome'];
```

}

Comment: Is this your expected solution?

Comment: see my edit at the top of my question. It is tagged from **EDIT** to **END EDIT**. No data are displayed anymore.

Comment: in the beginning of you success function log the `res` and see if your return data is as expected.

Comment: I saw it at the XHR, the array was divided, but can't see on the chart